# Two monitors, wrong order Windows 8.1

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

I have two (exactly the same model) monitors attached to the system.

The problem is Windows 8.1 (up to date) is failing to find out which is right and which is left. I am having to move my mouse to the LEFT side of the LEFT monitor in order to reach the second monitor which is illogical.

The fun thing is that, setting up certain monitor as primary is not helping.

Also I tried to change the order of coords, with no help!

The last thing is to change the physical order of monitors :D but may be there's a better solution for this weird situation?

Comment: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution` just drag and drop the **1** monitor to the left or right of the **2** monitor.

Comment: lol this worked.

Comment: Of course it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to the following Control Panel Applet

`All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution`

Then arrange the monitors by dragging and dropping them to the left or right of one another.